# Search through asset folder

Tags: android

I want to make an app with 2 html files at my asset folder:
one.html and two.html
Then when some body type in my edittext: one, it opens the one.html.

Is that possible and how can i do that.
I have this code but i don't now what to do with it:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = null;
try {
    files = assetManager.list("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error loading assets", e.getMessage());
}
for (String file : files) {
    if (file.equals("one.html")) {
        Open the html with webview
    else if (file.equals("two.html")) {
        Open the html with webview
}
}
```

So do you now how i can search trough my asset folder with an `EditText`?

Comment: You  should implement the TextWatcher interface for the EditText and after that, you can load the data coming from both html files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one edittext and one webview. if you write file name in edit text then your webview will load the file from assets folder and show it

### Sudo code

```
String str = editText.getText().toString() +".html"
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+str);
```

Comment: So this is the code, But is there an option that when whatever i type, for example: hello, it loads: hello.html?

Comment: The first editText says: editText can not be resolved. when i change it to EditText, it says: EditText can not be resolved or is not an field. the last thing thats red is: loadUrl: The method loadUrl(String) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (). Can you change it for me so it wil right. my EditText id is editText1. I hope you can help me.

Comment: try the above code now. By mistake i have written edittext twice. try the code now

Comment: String str = editText.getText().toString() +".html"
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"`str`);

Comment: I now i'm an beginner of android programming. But you new code works, but one thing not: the str thing by webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"str) is red and it says: Syntax error on token "str", delete this token

Comment: But when i press the "Go" button it checks the editText, so is my code good:

Comment: Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             String str = edit.getText().toString() +".html";
             webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+str);            }
        });
    }  
 
    
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you say "with an `EditText`" but placing files in the asset folder means you can read through them using java's `File` class.

Just google for a tutorial on how to search files through directories, here are two of them:

- [Finding Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)
- [How do I search for files recursively?](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/359.html)